# How to fit a GAM including continuous and categorical variables

Tags: regression, generalized-additive-model

I have data on number of seedlings, sapling and adults of 8 tree species along elevation gradient on two aspects (north- and south-facing) at two sites. On each aspect, the elevation gradient was divided into elevation bands that were 100 m apart. In each elevation band I have recorded the number of seedlings, saplings and adults of 8 different tree species.

Now what would be the most appropriate GAM given the type of variables that I have. I want to know whether or not site, aspect and elevation affect the number of seedlings, saplings and adults of each species. Being very raw in GAM, your help would be very helpful